# How can I do actions in buttons of a UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` from a reload button with 2 buttons - OK and Cancel. Cancel button works fine but when I want put some action (play again the game) in OK button doesn't work unless that action be a `NSLog`.

My code in m. file:

```
- (IBAction)startAgainAction:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                         initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Have you short that want start again the game?" 
                         delegate:self 
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                         otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // My OK button

    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {

        // Action to start the game again... (don't work)
        [self viewDidLoad];

    } else if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {

        // NSLog it's accept but not other actions...
        NSLog(@"Cancel");
    }

}
```

And yes, I have put `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol in h. file

So, why `viewDidLoad` doesn't work when it calls the method again?

Comment: Why might I ask are you trying to call viewDidLoad yourself?

Comment: Also, if you're action doesn't work but NSLog does, there's probably something wrong with said action. Post the code for that and show how you're calling it.

Comment: Because I need to reload the game, initialize everything, like the start.

Comment: I forgot say that UIAlertView is called from a UIButton that is inside a UIView which acts as popover.

Comment: @tixa You should have a different method for initializing then.  Re-calling `viewDidLoad` is bad practice.  Instead write a `gameInitialize` function and call that from within `viewDidLoad`

Comment: It will helpful for us to take a look on your viewDidLoad method and also the other method or action that you are trying to do above the NSLog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reloading ... you should make a

```
- (void)reloadGame {}
```

method and reset everything manually. Something like:

```
- (void)reloadGame {
self.highScore = 0; 
self.ballPosition = ... 
// etc. depends on what you have
}
```

Also you could define some constants so you won't hardcode everything. and give them both in ViewDidLoad and reloadGame ... or better yet ... move all your code inside viewDidLoad into reloadGame and change it as so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self reloadGame];
}
```

---

Instead of having 2 .m files for the same class:
You should make your popOver class a different one and set it's delegate to your game class:

in your popOver class you should do:

```
@protocol CustomPopoverViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)doSomething;
// add other methods you need 
@end

@interface  CustomPopoverView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <CustomPopoverView> delegate;
```

and when you open your popOver in your game class you should add:

```
//popover init/alloc 
popover.delegate = self; 
//show popover
```

also make sure your game class listens tot the popover delegate method

```
#import "CustomPopoverView.h"
@interface GameViewClass : UIViewController <CustomPopoverViewDelegate>
```

and in your customPopover class in a method you want to forward to your gameclass you just put

```
- (void)methodNameForDoSomething {
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)]) {   //always nice to check. Notice this is the same doSomething we declared in .h in the protocol 
    [self.delegate doSomething];
}
}
```

and the gameClass you will put

```
- (void)doSomething {
//whatever 
}
```

you can also send parameters

---

You could also subclass ... (of course popover be another class with it's own .h)

and declare it as a subclass (you can do this when creating a new class and enter the class name you want to subclass as seen in the pic below)

[image]

and the your popover view's header will be like :

```
@interface  CustomPopoverView : GameView
```

and will have all of GameView's methods and propertyes available.

Comment: I will be more specific. I have a plus button in my navigation bar and when I click it appears a UIView like popover which have 4 buttons one of them is a reload button. I put a UIAlertView in reload button for user confirm or not if want start the game from begin. This UIAlertView have 2 buttons - OK and Cancel - both work fine with NSLog but when I call methods like viewDidLoad or others (any others) don't work. The View that acts like popover and the View of game has the same m. file for I can call the methods.

Comment: you don't have and you shouldn't call viewDidLoad yourself. Also I don't it's ok that two different views use the same .m file. A better approach would be through subclasing or delegates.

Comment: Yes, I changed the code to call a method and not the viewDidLoad. Thanks for that.
But, I really don't know how can I call inside my popover UIView the methods that I have in m. file of my UIView game for I can reload the game. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I took a quick look on it in a search of the Internet, but how can I implement it in this case?

Comment: I have tried subclass and it is nice. Now, inside subclass popover how I call the reloadGame method? Because [self reloadGame] isn't accepted.

Comment: do  you also have it declared in your .h file ... although if I think about it ... it won't work .. since they you do not have the exact instance of the GameView. Last case scenario you could just add a @property(nonatomic,retain) GameView *gameView in you popover ... and when you present your popover assign you GameView to it's gameView property and you will be able to call actions directly on your instance of GameView.    [gameView doSomething];

Comment: Well,  [gameView doSomething]; . For example,  I used gameView.indexArray = 0; to set the variable to 0 again since I can't access to [gameView reloadGame];  but it didn't work too.

Comment: Well, [gameView doSomething]; didn't work. For example, I used gameView.indexArray = 0; to set the variable to 0 again since I can't access to [gameView reloadGame]; but it didn't work too.